# Add custom headers coming from android webview

Tags: android, webview

I need to add custom headers to EVERY request coming from the `WebView`. I know `loadURL` has the parameter for adding extra Headers, but those are only applied to only some of the requests.
All (resource related) requests do not contain the headers.
I have looked at all overrides in `WebViewClient`, but nothing allows for adding headers to resource requests - `onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)` and `shouldInterceptRequest(Webview,url)`. Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 9):

`shouldInterceptRequest(Webview,url)` can help you to intercept every request of a site, such as JavaScript, CSS, Image. Then inside `shouldInterceptRequest(Webview,url)` you can use the parameter `url` to initial new http request by using `HttpClient` and `HttpPOST`, here is example code :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(<"your url for each request">);
httpPost.setHeader("<header-name>", "<header-value>");
HttpReponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

//here omit getting content-type and encoding

InputStream reponseInputStream = httpReponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

Then you can put `responseInputStream` to `return WebResourceResponse(<content-type>, <encoding>, reponseInputStream)` in your `shouldInterceptRequest(Webview,url)`

if you have any request which doesn't need add more header, just filter it and `return null`, `shouldInterceptRequest(Webview,url)` will do the rest.

Hope this can help.

Comment: We are developing a browser which sends request to proxy and proxy sends data back to browser.So, every request should go to proxy with custom header and shows the page from proxy.In this, how can we intercept only resource related requests.Resources types are so many, like CSS,JS,PNG,JPEG,etc... So, how can I handle this.

Comment: only resource related requests, I suppose you dont want to add headers to web page itself, you can just filter it in `ShouldInterceptRequest()` using request's content-type other than "text/html".

Comment: How can I get content-type from request? As far as I know, we can get only from response.

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentType()). Using `httpResponse.getEntity()` to get the `HttpEntity`.

Comment: shouldInterceptRequest() is not called for repeated resource urls hence not able to add my custom header. for e.g. for the first time when url1 is called shouldInterceptRequest() is called but for the second time when url1 is called shouldInterceptRequest() is not called.

Comment: @admar.kevin What is HttpResponse? What library are you getting this from. It's not available for me with default Android SDK.

Comment: @clu please refer to "Apache HTTP Client Removal Section" in http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html